# How to add a marker with a custom image on a Google Map in the component "vue2-google-maps"?

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2

I use [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) for add Google Map on page.
How can I replace the standard marker picture?

```
<gmap-map style="width: 100%; height: 289px;"
                      :center="{lat: 55.750055, lng: 37.665277}"
                      :zoom="16"
            >
                <gmap-marker
                    :position="{lat: 55.750055, lng: 37.665277}"
                    :icon="{iconImageHref: http://inter-service.info/assets/templates/dist/images/icons/marker.svg}"
                >
                </gmap-marker>
            </gmap-map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

`:icon="{url:'/src/assets/img/A.png'}"`

Comment: It doesn't work.. The markers just disappear.. It's a bug